# how to read filenames from anouther file in ssis

Tags: ssis

how to read file names from another file in ssis using script task

I tried the bellow code but i am getting single file
my requirement is to read one file at a time and load data into table.

```
public void Main()
        {
            String filename = Dts.Variables["filename"].Value.ToString();
            using (System.IO.StreamReader rdr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename))
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::filename"].Value = rdr.ReadLine();


            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }


      class for setting the

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: Make this variable `User::filename` as object and fill it with this list. After that put `Loop task`, which will help insert data.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ScriptMain
{
  public void Main()
  {
    const string FILE_PATTERN = ""(your file pattern);

    string Folder;
    string[] Files;

    Folder = Dts.Variables["Folder"].Value.ToString();
    Files = Directory.GetFiles(Folder, FILE_PATTERN);

    Dts.Variables["Files"].Value = Files;

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
  }
}
and also you can read this for :                                    http://www.msbiguide.com/2013/09/looping-through-files-using-foreach-loop-container-in-ssis-2008-r2/
```